# How to clear convertView

Tags: android, listview, convertview

I have a row in a listview that I need to change its layout dynamically. In my array adapter I have the following (simplified) code

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.default);
    }
    ...

    if(condition) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new);
        ...
        return view; // doesn't work
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

My actual listview is actually pretty complex and I am also using the `getViewType` for the two different layouts. But the above code should be enough to make my point that the new layout won't display correctly when I want to switch layout dynamically.

My question is, how can I refresh the convertView, or trigger a reload of the adapter/listview to the point that the convertViews will be cleared? I've tried calling `notifyDataSetChanged`, or calling the listview `invalidateViews()` but they all didn't worked. My last resort seems to restart the whole activity but I don't think this is an elegant solution.

Comment: Why not use getViewType with additional view type (it's possible change view type on some position dinamically)?

Comment: This could be because you don't have an `else` block here. Try adding the `else` code: perhaps, just `return convertView;`.